# Swift 3.0 CloudKit fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit, swift3

I am following along a [WWDC Session about CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231/). In this, there was this code snipped:

```
let changesOperation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: privateDatabaseChangeToken)
//(...)
changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = {
        (newToken: CKServerChangeToken?, more: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // error handling here
        self.sharedDBChangeToken = newToken // cache new token
        self.fetchZoneChanges(callback) // using CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation
    }
```

Even though the code was exactly copied from the slides, XCode spilled out this error:

> Cannot assign value of type '(CKServerChangeToken?, Bool, NSError?) -> Void' to type '((CKServerChangeToken?, Bool, Error?) -> Void)?'

I am using XCode 8.0 Beta 4 and the target is iOS 10, in case this should be a compiler error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Beta 4<sup>*[citation needed]*</sup>, the swift-evolution proposal [SE-0112](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md) was implemented, affecting error handling.

The important bit here is that Objective-C `NSError` types are imported in Swift as `Error` (formerly `ErrorProtocol`) types instead of `NSError`.

Just update your type annotation:

```
changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = {
    (newToken: CKServerChangeToken?, more: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

---

As a side note, you can actually omit the parameter types entirely:

```
changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { newToken, more, error in
    // ...
}
```

---

For error handling, from what I can tell the error passed is often a [`CKError`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckerror), which is a new(?) struct which encapsulates all(?) of the `userInfo` dictionary on the old `NSError`.

```
changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { newToken, more, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
            // ... Handle the CKError
        }
        return
    }
    // ... Do something useful
}
```